# Hide an alert in scalajs-react

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, alert, scalajs-react

I'm using scalajs-react and I'd like to hide a bootstrap alert instead of removing it from the DOM.
I found this javascript code [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/1845)

```js
$('.alert .close').on('click', function () {
  $(this).parent().hide();
})
```

Which I wrongly translated to scalajs-react with the following code:

```
.componentDidMount(scope => Callback {
    jQuery(scope.getDOMNode()).on("click", null, null, Alert.closed _)
  }
```

The obvious problem is that it hides the alert when I click anywhere on it (not only on the button). How can I translate this $('.alert .close')?

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing a selector in the on() method.
The solution is:

```
jQuery(scope.getDOMNode()).on("click", ".close", null, Alert.closed _)
```